# Passing a Request from React.JS front-end to C# back-end (ASP.NET) using HTTP Post (RESTful API)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs

Sorry for the messy title - I'm new to web development and am unsure of how to best phrase this.

## My Goal

- I want to **click a button** on my React.js front-end, and have the C# back-end activate a GPIO in response.
- After researching a bit, I would like to use an HTTP Post function, but am not sure where to start.
- **Simply put:** I want to *call a C# function from my React.js front-end*

## What I Have so far:

- React.JS file: **RoomComponent.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class RoomComponent extends Component {
  static displayName = RoomComponent.name;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = { lightOn: true };
      this.turnOnLight = this.turnOnLight.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // call turn on light function, where HTTP post is used to send on signal to back-end
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.turnOnLight}>Toggle LED</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

    async turnOnLight() {
       // here i would use HTTP post with a "fetch" function? How do I send data here?
        alert("LED toggled");
    }
}
```

- C# file: **Lighting.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace control.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LightingController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly int ledPin = 11;
        private GpioController controller = new GpioController();
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        
        [HttpPost]
        public void turnOnLed()
        {
            // somehow recieve JSON with data telling the GPIO to turn on, and activate it accordingly
            controller.Write(ledPin, PinValue.High);
        }
        public LightingController()
        {
            controller.OpenPin(ledPin, PinMode.Output);
        }
    }
}
```

## Where I'm Struggling

I'm having a hard time understanding how I would formulate the HTTP Post to communicate to the back-end that I want the GPIO to be activated. Examples online are always HTTP posting/getting information from remote URLs, but for me it's all contained within the same app. I would be super grateful for any advice or guidance with this, even other resources to help me better understand how to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: in your controller, under your class put  [RoutePrefix("api/Lighting")], in your action above it put  [HttpPost, Route("YourActionName")]. And in your front end, call your API like you would normally call it

Comment: How would I normally call it? I'm really new to all this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using .net core if I'm not mistaken. so do this...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace control.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    //[Route("[controller]")] Remove this
    public class LightingController : ControllerBase
    {
    private readonly int ledPin = 11;
    private GpioController controller = new GpioController();
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    

    //And add the route attribute to your endpoint
    [Route("api/turnOnLed")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void turnOnLed()
    {
        // somehow recieve JSON with data telling the GPIO to turn on, and activate it accordingly
        controller.Write(ledPin, PinValue.High);
    }
    public LightingController()
    {
        controller.OpenPin(ledPin, PinMode.Output);
    }
}
```

So basically just remove the Route("Controller") Attribute from your class and then add it to your endpoint but with "api/[the endpoint name]" which is turnOnLed. It should work.